# bitwise and operator discrepancy in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, bitwise-and

bitwise operator is resulting in incorrect response in javascript, compared with the same in python. Following is the code snippet, can someone help me with this regard?

```
# Python
===========================
$ cat bitwise_example.py
x = 2650800128
y = 2684354559
m = x

while (x < y):
  m = m & x
  x += 1

print m
============
$ python bitwise_example.py
2650800128
===========================


# JavaScript
===========================
$ cat bitwise_example.js
let x = 2650800128;
let y = 2684354559;
let m = x;

while (x < y) {
  m = m & x;
  x += 1;
}

console.log(m);
============
$ node bitwise_example.js
-1644167168
========================
```

Comment: Not an answer, but it looks like you are doing an _enormous_ number of bit shfit operations, on the order of millions.  Doing that, it's possible to pick up quite a bit of rounding error, as well as changing the sign due to two's complement stuff.  Maybe you should let us know what is the purpose behind this actual code.

Comment: hey @TimBiegeleisen, I was doing a coding challenge in JavaScript and some tests were failing in running with JS. So was curious to know about the behaviour

Comment: Python has infinite precision integers, Javascript just has 32 bits.

Comment: It says [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) that in javascript all operands of bitwise operators are converted to 32 bit signed integers. You can just observe the results of evaluating `2650800128 & 2650800129` on python and javascript.

Comment: true, looks like its the limitation with JS, is their any alternative to get to the right solution with JS?